# ANTLR4: What is the best approach to implement C like include file handling?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am implementing a lexer/parser for the real-time language OpenPEARL. For better struturing of my testsuite I want to implement a include file handling similiar to C/C++. The parser iteself uses the visitors. What would be the best approach to implement this? One thing which concern me when instantiating a nested parser the included file does not need to contain a complete program depending where it is included.

Cheers

Marcel

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for ANTLR, but in general one implements a C-like preprocessor in the lexer.

You accomplish this by having a *stack* of input streams, with the base of the stack being the source file.  You read input from the stream on top of the stack.

When an include is encountered *in the lexer*, a new stream is pushed on top of the stack, and reading continues (now from the new stream).  When a stream encounters EOF, you pop the stack and continue; if the stack is empty, the lexer emits an EOF token.

You can abuse these streams to implement macros.  On macro call, simply push a new stream that represents the macro body.  When you encounter a macro parameter name, push a stream for the argument supplied to the corresponding macro.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen implementations where include handling has been done in the (parser) grammar. Doing it in the lexer like Ira suggests is certainly possible, but with some extra work.

However, full include handling is more than simply switching input streams, namely macro handling, line splicing, trigraph handling, charizing and stringizing + as evaluator for #if(def) commands. All that I have implemented in my [Windows Resource File Parser](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/java/windows-resource-file-parser-and-converter), which was written for ANTLR 2.7 and hence needs an update, but is certainly good for getting ideas.

In this project I handle include files outside of the normal ANTLR parsing chain, which follows more the preprocessor approach you often see for C/C++.

Comment: How would that work for C? #include directives can occur *anywhere*.  I agree, if the language grammar contains the include directive explicitly, then one can do the stream stacking on reduction of the "include_directive" rule.  (My PARLANSE compiler [see bio] does this).    I prefer this approach over the lexer-based one,...

Comment: ...  but when the preprocessor is independent of the language, I don't see how to handle this in the parser.  We build a full C and a full C++ front end; the *lexer* does the basic recognition of the prepreprocessor tokens and stream switching; a preprocessor pass between the lexer and the parser handles parsing the preprocessor directives (if conditionals have complexe expression, stringizing, etc.)

Comment: Hmm, I can't find an example for the parser approach atm. Only a discussion about the approach in general: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/antlr-discussion/include|sort:relevance/antlr-discussion/FUQbEtonUlw/zFKdMU9ADAAJ. Handling it in the Lexer (or input stream as I did) is totally fine.